# Enable text selection personalized UI Panel Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I would like to enable text selection in the Docking Panels created in my Forge Viewer. I've seen that the Properties Panel from the viewer, has the text selection enabled:

[image: Text selecion Properties panel]

I'm trying to enable it in other Docking panels created from my extensions:

[image: Personalized docking panel]

Is there any property I need to enable?
If it's not possible to select the text, is there a way I could download the information from the panel in a .txt or pdf?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the UI in the Viewer (whether it's built-in or yours) is just vanilla HTML/CSS. If some of the UI doesn't let you select the text, it's possible that its [user-select](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/u/user-select/) CSS property is set to `none`. Try to [inspect](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/inspect-element-in-chrome) the HTML elements in the problematic UI, and see if the `user-select` property is set somewhere in there, and if it is, you should be able override it with your own CSS.

Comment: Thank you very much. It resvolved the problem